# take so long vs taking so long

Tags: grammar, tenses, sentence, formality, politeness

I've worked in a market. Suddenly they stopped my work for verification purpose. They requested me to provide a student ID card. I've sent a scanned copy of my Student ID card for verification. One week has gone still now they have not sent any confirmation email. How do I politely and without any grammatical error ask them about my verification delay?

If I want to say something like this, is it correct?

> Hi Admin, Why are you pending my Student ID verification? Why do you
>   taking so long to verify my ID?

Here which sentence is appropriate in this perspective.

*Why do you take so long to verify my ID?

Why do you taking so long to verify my ID?

Why does it take so long to verify my ID?*

You can suggest some additional formal and polite sentence. 
Thank you.

Comment: This is not polite at all. Indeed it's quite aggressive. Drop the questions. Especially if they are *why* questions. Those will always come off as exceptionally rude, even when that's not your intention at all.

Comment: That said, that is not specific to English. It's either polite or it isn't, no matter what language you use. If you work to earn another 9 reputation points, you'll be able to access our chat and simply take any questions of this kind there.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Please remove my hold!

Comment: @RashedulAlam As a question about grammar, this is probably better asked on [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) (it's basic grammar which is what they care about there). But as to how to make a polite request, maybe [Interpersonal Skills.SE](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/) is better.

Answer (score 1):

The question written in this way might be mis-interpreted and come across as rude or accusatory.
Try using the word 'please' in your question for a more polite way of phrasing the question. For example:
'Please could you let me know what might be causing the delay in verifying my Student ID?'